# ioutil.TempFile and umask

Tags: go, io

In my Go application instead of writing to a file directly I would like to write to a temporary that is renamed into the final file when everything is done. This is to avoid leaving partially written content in the file if the application crashes.

Currently I use ioutil.TempFile, but the issue is that it creates the file with the 0600 permission, not 0666. Thus with typical umask values one gets the 0600 permission, not expected 0644 or 0660. This is not a problem is the destination file already exist as I can fix the permission on the temporary to much the existing ones, but if the file  does not exist, then I need somehow to deduce the current umask.

I suppose I can just duplicate ioutil.TempFile implementation to pass 0666 into os.OpenFile, but that does not sound nice. So the question is there a better way?

Comment: Is there any reason to not just use [`os.(*File).Chmod`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Chmod) to change the file mode of the returned file?

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I cannot use Chmod as I do not know what should be the permission for the final file unless it already exists when I could copy permissions from it.

Comment: You can always figure out the current umask (`current_umask := syscall.Umask(0) syscall.Umask(current_umask)` ) at startup, and apply that when you Chmod your desired permissions.

Comment: That is not portable and may not work even on Linux with, for example, fuse filesystems.

Comment: Really good question and still no answer:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite grok your problem.

Temporary files *must* be created with as tight permissions as possible because the whole idea of having them is to provide your application with *secure* means of temporary storing data which is too big to fit in memory (or to hand the generated file over to another process).  (Note that on POSIX systems, where an opened file counts as a live reference to it, it's even customary to immediately remove the file while having it open so that there's no way to modify its data other than writing it from the process which created it.)

So in my opinion you're trying to use a wrong solution to your problem.

So what I do in a case like yours is:

1. Create a file with the same name as old one but with the ".temp" suffix appended.
2. Write data there.
3. Close, rename it over the old one.

If you feel like using a fixed suffix is lame, you can "steal" the implementation of picking a unique non-conflicting file name from `ioutil.TempFile()`.  But IMO this would be overengeneering.

Comment: I do not want to use a common .temp name so it is easier to see if a temporary file is leftover from a resent application crash or from a milder bug in the previous application run. But you are right that I do not need to protect against malicious code trying to replace my files with symlinks. That require a write access to the directory and with such access the code can go directly to files. So just using .temp_timestamp is enough.

Comment: @IgorBukanov, if you like, I once created an internal package, [`tempfile`](https://gist.github.com/kostix/63949f9ff6d8fc79c6d8), for one of my programs which mimics `mkstemp(3)` and `mkstemps(3)` libc calls. It has been used in production for some time (before I transitioned to `ioutil.TempFile()`). May be you could find it useful as it actually implements what glibc is doing. Note that you'd need to tweak the file mode on line 82 to adapt it to your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ioutil.TempDir`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempDir) to get the folder where temporary files should be stored an than create the file on your own with the right permissions.

Comment: TempDir requires to remove the dir after the final file rename or, when, for example, the temporary creation fails for any reason. That brings complexity which duplicating ioutil.TempFile does not have. Still this is a good option especially if one needs to write several files as in my case.

Comment: @IgorBukanov: From the docs "If dir is the empty string, TempDir uses the default directory for temporary files". So just get the default folder and create a file there.

Comment: that does not work as the default temp dir may not be on the same filesystem as the folder where I need to write files

Answer (score 1):

Matching exactly the requirements of the question, that should do:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/fs"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "syscall"
)

func getCurrentUmask() int {
    // Get current umask
    currentUmask := syscall.Umask(0)
    // Restore it to previous value
    syscall.Umask(currentUmask)
    // Return the value
    return currentUmask
}

func atomicWriteFile(filename string, data []byte, perm os.FileMode) error {
    reader := bytes.NewBuffer(data)
    dataSize := int64(len(data))

    tmpFile, err := os.CreateTemp(filepath.Dir(filename), ".tmp-"+filepath.Base(filename))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = os.Chmod(tmpFile.Name(), perm)
    if err != nil {
        tmpFile.Close()

        return err
    }

    n, err := io.Copy(tmpFile, reader)
    if err == nil && n < dataSize {
        tmpFile.Close()

        return io.ErrShortWrite
    }

    if err != nil {
        tmpFile.Close()

        return err
    }

    if err := tmpFile.Sync(); err != nil {
        tmpFile.Close()

        return err
    }

    if err := tmpFile.Close(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return os.Rename(tmpFile.Name(), filename)
}

func main() {
    // Whatever permission you would normally set on your file
    targetPermissionForFile := 0o666

    // How you would normally write a file
    os.WriteFile("using_os.txt", []byte("barbar"), fs.FileMode(targetPermissionForFile))

    // Retrieving the current umask
    mask := getCurrentUmask()

    // Writing it with the atomic method
    atomicWriteFile("using_atomic.txt", []byte("foofoo"), fs.FileMode((^mask)&targetPermissionForFile))

    // Comparing resulting permissions
    info, _ := os.Stat("using_os.txt")
    fmt.Printf("File written using os.WriteFile has permissions: %#o\n", info.Mode())

    info, _ = os.Stat("using_atomic.txt")
    fmt.Printf("File written using atomicWrite has permissions: %#o\n", info.Mode())

}
```

Comment: Unix only, evidently. Also, calling `syscall.Umask` may come at a cost (?), so, maybe you just look it up when the app start and stash the value somewhere. And yeah, I know this is 7 years old, but was looking for an answer to that myself today.